# run command in on_message (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

1. Can I use ctx in `on_message()`?
2. If not, then can I make the command work in `on_message`?

**Example:**

```
# func.py
class function(self):   
    async def a(self, ctx):
    # content here


# bot.py
class Bot(self, commands.Bot):
    async def on_message(self, message):
    # make a() run here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use ctx in `on_message`, by getting it with `get_context(message)`.
2. You probably could execute a command by running it with argument got by `get_context`, but just using the `message` in `on_message` should be suitable for most tasks as it's similar to `ctx` and you can get all info almost the same way ([discord.message in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message)). `Message` is just like `ctx.message`.

**Using `message` parameter in `on_message()`:**

```py
class Bot(self, commands.Bot):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.author) #prints author of the message
        await message.channel.send("Hello") #sends Hello to the channel (same result as with ctx.send)
```

Comment: Point 1 is not true. You can use [`get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_context#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context) to get `context` from a `message`

Comment: @Benjin you're right I totally forgot about `get_context`. I edited my answer.